# assign values to Jquery library method

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

    var lines = <?php echo $dataLines ?>;

        var d0 = lines[0];
        var d1 = lines[1];

    var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [
                    {data: d0},{data: d1}],options);


});
```

The above code is the correct code, but the number of the lines are hard-coded. In order to make it flexiable, I used "For Loop" to get the amount of lines automatically. However, it doesn't work when I did changes(see the following code).

I guess there is something wrong on `plot.data = di`inside of For Loop.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

    var lines = <?php echo $dataLines ?>;


    var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),options);

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){

        plot.data = di;  //somthing wrong here

        }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
    //get the next value
    var newLine = lines[i];
    //create an object with the new value
    var dataToAdd = {data: newLine};
    //add the object to the array
    plot.data.push(dataToAdd); 

}
```

in this way you add an object to the array `plot.data`

Comment: don't forget to initialize the data array - `plot.data = [];` before starting the loop!

Comment: @VinayC i thought that data was initialized by the plugin, so i din't include array initialization